# How to send the OAuth Dialog from php server to javascript client

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I've already added a php script (server side) to my programme, and i can login, logout and retreive informations from Facebook. My JavaScript client can retreive those informations from the server by calling the methods using urls, but can't login to Facebook.

Is there a way, a script able to send the OAuth Dialog from a php app (server side) to a Javascript client?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to encode the result with a json_encode() function and get it through a GET with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "sending" a dialog will work.

JavaScript Facebook API works as a popup while Facebook PHP API works as redirect.

The best way would be implementing OAuth through JavaScript on client, sending received token thought HTTPS to server and letting PHP do the work by itself or thought AJAX calls from the client side.

Another option - opening popup through JavaScript with a PHP page inside. The page does the authentication and closes itself.

Cheers.

Comment: Openning popup through Javascript with PHP page inside works !